# Получение сообщений с VK

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, javafx

Пишу приложение-мессенджер для VK на Java. Просто что бы потренироваться.
В отдельном потоке с заданным интервалом слать запрос, парсить ответ и если в ответе есть новые сообщения, то информировать пользователя?

Comment: Не это  https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll случаем нужно?

Comment: Не ясно, что собственно спрашивается